# How to hide date on Tumblr pages?

Tags: tumblr, date

The documentation on Tumblr (https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#dates) says

> {block:Date} {/block:Date}
>   Rendered for all posts.
>   Always wrap dates in this block so they will be properly hidden on non-post pages.

.. but I see "December 31st 1969" on all my static pages. I am currently using the theme "Optica" (which seems to be the default theme). Is there any way to hide the date on pages?

Alternatively, is there a way to set a date for a tumblr page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug on Tumblr's site. I wrote in to Tumblr support over this, and this was their reply:

> Our engineers are aware of this issue and are currently working on a fix. We hope to have the problem resolved shortly. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: This issue is fixed!